# SQL: Lookup values in another table and update them

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`.

```
table1              table2
======              ======
varA     varB       varA     varC
-----------------   ----------------
A        ?          A        3
A        ?          B        2
B        ?          C        1
C        ?
```

How can I lookup the values varB in `table1` using `table2` and insert them in `table1`? The result should be:

```
varA    varB
-----------------
A       3
A       3
B       2
C       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
update table1 a
join table2 b on b.vara = a.vara
set a.varb = b.varc
```

Result:

```
vara  varb
----  ----
A        3
A        3
B        2
C        1
```

Sample data:

```
create table table1 (vara varchar(6), varb int);

insert into table1 (vara, varb) values ('A', null), ('A', null),
  ('B', null), ('C', null);

create table table2 (vara varchar(6), varc int);

insert into table2 (vara, varc) values ('A', 3), ('B', 2), ('C', 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the `update ... join ...` syntax:

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.vara = t2.vara
set t1.varb = t2.varc
```

Note that, for this to work properly, `vara` must be a unique key in `table2` (otherwise, the query wouldn't be able to identify a unique source row for `update`).

Comment: Any idea why you'd get the "expecting SET" when trying to assign Table1 to t1 ?